# Why does piping a BehaviorSubject create an AnonymousSubject in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, behaviorsubject, subject-observer

When creating an RxJS `BehaviorSubject`, it stays a `BehaviorSubject` until it's `pipe`'d. As soon a `pipe`'d version is returned, it becomes an `AnonymousSubject`.

## Examples:

```js
// Instance of `BehaviorSubject`
const behaviorSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject({ someValue: null })

// Suddenly becomes an Anonymous Subject
const anonymousSubject$ = (
    behaviorSubject$
    .pipe(
        pluck('someValue')
    )
)

// Also suddenly becomes an Anonymous Subject
const anonymousSubject$ = (
    new BehaviorSubject({ someValue: null })
    .pipe(
        pluck('someValue')
    )
)
```

I experience this same issue with `ReplaySubject` as well. I can't seem to pipe through the subject and return that subject back. It always converts to an `AnonymousSubject`. I think what I'm looking for here is Promise-like behavior where I can subscribe to this observable from anywhere and grab the one value passed into it.

Comment: Do you have code that cares? If you do you shouldn't.

Comment: I need to do `behaviorSubject$.value`. Should I be using a `ReplaySubject` instead?

Comment: You need to pass an argument to BehaviorSubject()

Comment: Why do you need the `value` from the result returned from `pipe` though?

Comment: IMO using `value` is a code smell and even if `lift` returned a `BehaviorSubject`, what would you expect the `value` if the lifted subject to be? The original value or the plucked value? I think you should seriously reconsider using `value`.

Comment: Changed my example to show I'm passing a value. Also, I don't have to use `.value`, but even if I use a `ReplaySubject` instead, it converts to an `AnonymousSubject`, and I lose the value I passed.

Comment: A pipe essentially returns an observer|observable combo (also called a Subject...) which emits values based on its source upon subscription. I don't see why the observer type matters. All you need to know is that you can subscribe to this observer to receive it values after all operators are processed

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` allows you to do `subject.value`. I can't do that with `AnonymousSubject`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening due to [`lift`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774407/rx-js-understanding-the-lift-method) called on [`Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/388c4852948660abcff22d7b82ccb0a29c77428c/src/internal/Subject.ts#L55).

Let's take a deeper look at your example:

1. You are instantiating a `BehaviorSubject` which extends
   `Subject`
2. You are calling `pluck` operator which [internally](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/e0c5b7c790bb9d99fa8bee26c805b5e70c1e456b/src/internal/operators/pluck.ts#L53) calls
   `map` operator
3. `map` operator [internally](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/df0ea7c78767c07a6ed839608af5a7bb4cefbde5/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L47) calls `lift` on `BehaviorSubject` which is delegated to `Subject` which then returns an `AnonymousSubject`